# terraform conditional module with dependency

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I'm using terraform 0.14 and  have two modules which conditionally will be created.
Second module has implicit dependency on first module:

```
   module "rg-sample" {
  count        = var.environment != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  source       = "../Modules/module-az-rg"
  name         = "rg-${var.environment}-vnet"
  location     = var.location
  tags         = var.tags
  deletelock   = false
  readonlylock = false
}

module "vnet" {
  count               = var.environment != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  source              = "../Modules/module-az-vnet"
  name                = "vnet-${var.environment}-01"
  location            = module.rg-sample.location
  resource_group_name = module.rg-sample.name
  address_space       = var.address_space
}
```

I get below error for second module:

> Error: Unsupported attribute
> resource_group_name  = module.rg-sample.name

If I use variables instead of modules properties there won't be any implicit dependency and it will work but I prefer to use module properties for resource_group_name or location.

Comment: The error is about wrong attribute. What is the definition of your module? Does it take such an attribute?

Comment: in the second module you there is an attribute resource_group_name . If I pass a value directly without using  module.rg-sample.name it will work

Comment: Try with `module.rg-sample[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcin . I had to use below snippet:

```
module.rg-sample[0].name
```